# Android Studio : Barcode Scanner zxing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, zxing

Please can somebody help me I am really new to this.

Right now I have a firebase database with data the user added manually. I want an additional function that the user can scan the barcode and the barcode number will come up and they can enter the details this way and save it to the database. The next time they scan that item the fields will already be there.

This is the code I have for the barcode scanner. I want to add the fields to enter text into the result handler with the barcode number plus additional details being saved to the database.

Please can anybody help me I am so lost.

```
package com.virtual.fridge.BarcodeScanner;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



import android.support.v7.widget.
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.virtual.fridge.Manifest;
import com.virtual.fridge.R;

    import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

    import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
    /*SOURCE:
        https://github.com/priyankapakhale/QRBarcodeScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otkz5Cwdw38&t=3s
   */

public class BarcodeDetect extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
private static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(scannerView);
    int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(currentApiVersion >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    if(checkPermission())
    {
        Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        requestPermission();
    }
}
}
private boolean checkPermission()
{
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BarcodeDetect.this, CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (cameraAccepted){
                    Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else

                    {
                    Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA},
                                                        REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeDetect.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            if(scannerView == null) {
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                setContentView(scannerView);
            }
            scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            scannerView.startCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(BarcodeDetect.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void handleResult(me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.Result result) {
        String result_text=result.getContents();
        if(result_text!=null && !result_text.isEmpty()){
           /* you can fetch your fields here and can write code to save in    database here */



        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.